# Auto Populate Test Data for Moodle 3.*

Tags: testing, moodle

Is there any way I can populate test data of Users, Course, course categories, cohert, group, Submissions, attempts, etc for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Behat is the official framework to test Moodle.

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Behat_integration

Using "Given..." in so-called "scenarios" you can create temporary data which will be erased after testing.

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Writing_acceptance_tests#Create_your_own_tests